# iPhone and iPad don't play audio for certain videos

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, video

Here's the metadata from a video file that does not work on iPad and iPhone. Does anything about the audio stick out at you?

```
avprobe version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:26:50 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Introduction.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.2.100
  Duration: 00:07:54.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1148 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 924 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 216 kb/s
```

Comment: With app are you using on the iPad/iPhone to play the video?

Comment: We are using Safari. Here's a direct link: https://cbg.nrtsalespro.com/videos/buyers-consultation-part

Comment: Audio doesn't play in Safari 12 for macOS as well, not even if I use the URL of the video file (https://cbg.nrtsalespro.com/system/files/video_server/uploaded_videos/The%20buyer%27s%20Consultation%20-%20Introduction.mp4) directly. I also didn't have any luck with QuickTime Player.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now (and it's a very wide shoot to be honest) is the bit rate of the audio track. Can you get the video transcoded with a more standard bit rate (64 or 128), at least for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all - nothing in that metadata looks like it would be problematic.

- MP3 support is quite good
- h264 is one of the preferred codecs for iOS since quite some time.

You may have to check the correctness of the file or transcode it or get a more thorough error confpdition if ones like this fail to play on iOS.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the correctness?